# Error en la Query

Tags: java, hibernate

La idea de la Query es que me de los paises que empiecen por una letra dada.

```
 public static List PaisesQueEmpiezan(String letra) {
        String letraC =letra+"%";
        String nombrePais;
        List<String> nPaises = new ArrayList();
        Session sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();
        Query consulta;
        consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT country FROM Country where country like 'letraC'").setParameter("letraC", letraC);
        nPaises = consulta.getResultList();
        return nPaises;
    }
```

y este es el error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [letraC], expecting one of []
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:607)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:62)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error dice que no encuentra el parametro llamado *letraC*, esto es porque en la Query estas haciendo referencia mal al parametro, recuerda que los parametros en Query's se identifican con dos puntos (`:parametro`) no con comillas simples, intenta cambiar tu Query por la siguiente:

```
 consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT country FROM Country where country like :letraC ").setParameter("letraC", letraC);
```

Saludos!

Comment: Justamente era eso gracias